# MFC ShellTreeCtrl selected element full path

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to build a simple app that displays the full path of the directory i have chosen,
however the only thing i can get until now is the name of the directory:

```
void CFolderBrowserDlg::OnTvnSelchangedMfcshelltree1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTREEVIEW pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
*pResult = 0;
TVITEMW hItem = pNMTreeView->itemNew;
TCHAR szText[256];
hItem.pszText= szText;
hItem.cchTextMax= 256*sizeof(TCHAR);
hItem.mask= TVIF_TEXT;
TreeView_GetItem(pNMTreeView->hdr.hwndFrom,&hItem);
m_Folder= szText;
UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

this is my code. can you please advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CString fullpath;
HTREEITEM current = hItem.hItem;
while (current != NULL) 
{
   CString thistext = GetTreeCtrl()->GetItemText(current);
   fullpath = thistext + _T("\\") + fullpath;
   current = GetTreeCtrl()->GetParentItem(current);
}
```

this is the general idea although i didnt actually test this, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: i don't know what do you mean by GetTreeCtrl(), sorry i'm new to MFC

Comment: Well, if you are using CTreeView, then you have to use GetTreeCtrl() method to get the actual CTreeCtrl object, which is the class that has all the goodies that you'll need to interact with the actual tree control.

Answer (score 5):

You are over coding it. This works for me:

```
void CMFCdlg1Dlg::OnTvnSelchangedMfcshelltree1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTREEVIEW pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    m_Tree.GetItemPath(m_EditString, pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem);
    UpdateData(false);
}
```

Member variables are:

```
m_Tree, type CMFCShelltreeCtrl attached to the ShellTree control
m_EditString, type CString attached to the Edit control
```

You can even get a C-style string if you need it for something:

```
LPTSTR path = m_EditString.GetBuffer(0);
```